# CPU ussage goes 100% while running Java Program

Tags: java

My java program requires too much memory. When I run my program, after some time CPU usage goes to 100 % and programs and system halts. What I have tried is "Increase the java heap size but it's not help".

If anyone know what is going wrong please help me.

Here is my code which I am running(It's a Part of speech trainer which trains by brown corpus)

```
public void readBrownCorpus(String corpusPath) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(corpusPath));
        String corpusData = inputStream.readLine();
        String previousTag = "^";
        String wordWithTag[] = corpusData.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < wordWithTag.length; i++) {
            String word[] = wordWithTag[i].split("_");
            if (word != null && word.length != 2)
                throw new Exception("Error in the Format of Corpus");
            // If new tag found,insert this in both transitionTable and
            // emissionTable
            if (transitionTable.get(word[1]) == null) {
                insertTagInTransitionTable(word[1]);
                insertTagInEmissionTable(word[1]);
            }
            if (emissionTable.get(word[0]) == null) {
                insertWordinEmissionTable(word[0]);
            }

            updateTranstionTable(previousTag, word[1]);
            updateEmissionTable(word[0], word[1]);
            if (word[1].equals(".")) {
                previousTag = "^";
            } else {
                previousTag = word[1];
            }
            System.out.println(transitionTable.size());
        }
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null)
            inputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Here is the another function

```
// This is used to insert the newly found tag in the transition table
    private void insertTagInTransitionTable(String tag) throws CloneNotSupportedException
    {
        for(String key : transitionTable.keySet())
        {
            Row row=transitionTable.get(key);
            row.tagCount.put(tag, 0f);
        }
            // get a row from transition table
            Row newRow = (Row)transitionTable.get("^").Clone();
            for(String key: newRow.tagCount.keySet())
            {
                newRow.tagCount.put(key,0f);
            }
            transitionTable.put(tag, newRow);
    }

    // This is used to insert the newly found tag in the emissionTable
    private void insertTagInEmissionTable(String tag)
    {
            for(String key : emissionTable.keySet())
            {
                Row row = emissionTable.get(key);
                row.tagCount.put(tag, 0f);
            }
    }

    // This method insert the word in emission table
    private void insertWordinEmissionTable(String word) throws CloneNotSupportedException
    {
                 // get a row from emission table
                    Row newRow = (Row)emissionTable.get("#c1").Clone();
                    for(String key: newRow.tagCount.keySet())
                    {
                        newRow.tagCount.put(key,0f);
                    }
                    emissionTable.put(word, newRow);
    }

    // This method is used to update the transitionTable
        private void updateTranstionTable(String previousTag,String currentTag)
        {
            Row row = transitionTable.get(previousTag);
            row.tagCount.put(currentTag, row.tagCount.get(currentTag)+1);
        }

        // This method is used to update the emission table
        private void updateEmissionTable(String word,String tag)
        {
            Row row = emissionTable.get(word);
            row.tagCount.put(tag, row.tagCount.get(tag)+1);
        }
```

Comment: The CPU goes up to 100%, and you conclude that your program uses too much memory? Using too mch memory causes OutOfMermoryErrors. It doesn't cause the CPU to go to 100%. I would rather look for an infinite loop or something like that.

Comment: Probably you are creating large numbers of temporary objects and getting hit with GC overhead, but without seeing the code that manages your in-memory tables it will be hard to help.

Comment: Learn to use the tools in your IDE and the JDK.   The profiler (e.g. jvisualvm in the JDK) will tell you where time is spent in your program, and the debugger can tell you what your program sees allowing you to deduce why it behaves as it does.

Comment: @JBNizet I have checked with small file, everything is working fine... so it seems there is no infinite loop issue.... I am also tracking the things in JConsole and taskmanager CPU ussage is going 100% and everything stucks...

Comment: There's nothing in the code you have posted that is a problem, but it calls a few functions `insertTagInTransitionTable` that you haven't posted. Problem must be in one of those.

Comment: It may not be infinite, an exponential complexity algorithm like *O(c^n)* would work for small input but not large

Comment: As you say, for small file everything is right but with large file it goes up to 100% So the work it take to process that file get your cpu to go up to 100% and if you wait long enough, it should complete giving you whatever result you need

Comment: @JonatanCloutier I have waited for 1 hour but it is not working just keep in the stuck state.....

Comment: Post the definition of the tables `??? transitionTable = ???`

Comment: as said weston if the complexity is exponential, it can become way longer while the input is just a little bigger. at the moment with a simple complexity analysis your are at least O(n^3)

Comment: I wonder... it's working when I am running the same from the following command .... 
C:\Users\Jatin Khurana\workspace\POSTagger\bin>java -Xmx2024 postagger.POSTagger
 d://corpus    actually I have already increased the size of Java heap before in eclipse.... but it was not working there bu working here

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the full code or the data, so these might not solve it, but I can see areas to improve:

Code like this, spinning though every entry so far and setting a count to `0` is just going to get slower and slower. Remove it and handle the absence later on and treat as `0`.

```
//remove this
for(String key : transitionTable.keySet())
{
    Row row = transitionTable.get(key);
    row.tagCount.put(tag, 0f);
}

//Handle later on:
private void updateTranstionTable(String previousTag,String currentTag)
{
    Row row = transitionTable.get(previousTag);
    Integer tagCount = row.tagCount.get(currentTag);
    int newTagCount = tagCount==null ? 1 : tagcount.intValue() + 1;
    row.tagCount.put(currentTag, newTagCount);
}
```

This is more efficient in terms of memory as you don't store loads of entries for `0`s that will never get incremented. Plus it saves time placing those `0`'s in the `Map`s in the first place.

Comment: yes... you are right.... I have done this before and everything was working fine..... but now I need this 0 later(for smoothing the table ... if you know natural language processing)... that's why I have changed this program and doing this...

Answer (score 1):

I think that a Map is not the right data structure for this task. Couting element is nicely done by Multiset from the [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained) library.
As stated by the official documentation, this kind of code:

```
Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for (String word : words) {
    Integer count = counts.get(word);
    if (count == null) {
        counts.put(word, 1);
    } else {
      counts.put(word, count + 1);
    }
}
```

could always be translated using a Multiset which has the *count()* method which can easily check the number of times a specific element has been added to your data structure.

Maybe this kind of operation could improve a little your performance.
But as suggested before, you can check your program running a profiler and inspecting the code appropriately, in order to understand which are the parts that drain more resources.